# react-native android input text not centered

Tags: android, react-native

I'm using react-native in my App and I use TextInput native component as well.

The thing is on my android phone even if I use `textAlignVertical: 'center'` the input has padding bottom which it makes feel like its not aligned to center.

Tried to set paddingBottom to 0 but no chance.

Can someone explain me how to fix this?

[image]

- I can hide the border by using this prop `underlineColorAndroid: 'transparent'`
  ** How can I remove the pink padding from the screen?

Comment: do you have the height of the TextInput set?

Comment: no, i dont have the height set

Comment: setting paddingBottom: 0 brings down the cursor to the underline for me. Could you double check if everything else is correct?

Comment: yes, you are right, paddingBottom works, thanks alot @AakashSigdel

Comment: No problem. Could you answer the question and mark it answered?